# How to implement merkle hash tree in python

Tags: python

Running my code it keeps giving me an error:

> File "C:\Users\Joshua Ajogu Alfa\Desktop\merklehashtreebuild1.py",
> line 36, in 
> inputString = sys.argv[1] IndexError: list index out of range

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import hashlib,sys
    
class MerkleTreeNode:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.value = value
        self.hashValue = hashlib.sha256(value.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    
def buildTree(leaves,f):
    nodes = []
    for i in leaves:
        nodes.append(MerkleTreeNode(i))

    while len(nodes)!=1:
        temp = []
        for i in range(0,len(nodes),2):
            node1 = nodes[i]
            if i+1 < len(nodes):
                node2 = nodes[i+1]
            else:
                temp.append(nodes[i])
                break
            f.write("Left child : "+ node1.value + " | Hash : " + node1.hashValue +" \n")
            f.write("Right child : "+ node2.value + " | Hash : " + node2.hashValue +" \n")
            concatenatedHash = node1.hashValue + node2.hashValue
            parent = MerkleTreeNode(concatenatedHash)
            parent.left = node1
            parent.right = node2
            f.write("Parent(concatenation of "+ node1.value + " and " + node2.value + ") : " +parent.value + " | Hash : " + parent.hashValue +" \n")
            temp.append(parent)
        nodes = temp 
    return nodes[0]

inputString = sys.argv[1]
leavesString = inputString[1:len(inputString)-1]
leaves = leavesString.split(",")
f = open("merkle.tree", "w")
root = buildTree(leaves,f)
f.close()
```

Comment: Sounds like you're not calling the program with any arguments.

Comment: how do I call the program with an argument in windows comand line?

Comment: `python c:\path\to\program.py arguments` where arguments are space separated, e.g., `program.py 1 2 3` would be three arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the program with arguments like this:

```
python program.py something another
```

Also I think adding a except block or checking the length of arguments before is better:

```
try:
   inputString = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
   pass # <- do something if there's no argument

## OR
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
   inputString = sys.argv[1]
else:
   pass # <- do something
```

Answer (score 1):

you aren't passing the arguments to the file while starting it,
do it in this way:

```
python C:/path/to/your/python/file.py arg1 arg2 arg3 argn ...
```

to avoid any error consider to do:

```
   try:
       inputString = sys.argv[1]
   except ValueError:
       inputstring = input("please add your input string: ")
       # do anything you want if you dislike this
```

Note: remember that you always have a sys.argv list that contains only the filename `[main.py]`

Comment: Is there a way you can modify the last part of the code so I can just input the names and bring out the hash tree directly without putting it in a text file?

Answer (score 1):

## The error description

Hi there. The error you've got tells you that, at execution time, the program couldn't find any value at position 1 in the **arguments list**.

## A generic solution

As written in the [Python 3.10 official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html#id2) you can run a *example.py* Python script on Windows using the command `py example.py`. You can then add arguments like in the command written below.

```
py example.py argument1 argument2 ... argumentN
```

## An example

If you want to run the *example.py* python script on Windows passing the arguments `jack`, `oliver` and `134` you'll have to run the python script using the command below.

```
py example.py jack oliver 134
```

Referring to the [official python docs for sys library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html), launching the script as written above you will be able to access to that arguments using `sys.argv` List, for example:

```
import sys

sys.argv[0] # example.py
sys.argv[1] # jack
sys.argv[2] # oliver
sys.argv[3] # 134
```

Comment: Is there a way you can modify the last part of the code so I can just input the names and bring out the hash tree directly without putting it in a text file?

Answer (score 0):

sys.argv is set by the command you run (i'll treat windows since it's your situation)

maybe trying to run a small program like this one will help

```
import sys

print(*sys.argv)
```

the rule of `argv` is that the first argument (`sys.arg[0]`) is the name of your program as you writen it in the CLI and the next are strings that contains  each arguments you passed so running:

`python prog.py 2 arg1 arg2`
will set argv at :
`["prog.py", "2", "arg1", "arg2"]`

normaly a whitespace separate argument but you can use double quote to ignore them.

running:
`python prog.py 1 "arg1 arg2"`
will set argv at :
`["prog.py", "2", "arg1 arg2"]`

in your case it look like you are not giving any argument to your program since `argv[1]` does not exist.

Comment: Is there a way you can modify the last part of the code so I can just input the names and bring out the hash tree directly without putting it in a text file?

Comment: @kinwosabi this is another question, this question is about having the right argument (since it was your error) if you have other issue you should create another question with the actual problem of your hash tree